# What would a better implementation for associating an OnClickListener() for multiple views than this array method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener

So I have multiple Views(a combination of multiple text boxes and images) and I have attached an `onClickListener` to the views and then attached an onClick method to them and after that I have used a switch statement within an `onClick` for the same.

```
ConstraintLayout[] ll_but = new ConstraintLayout[10];

ll_but[0] = findViewById(R.id.success_stories_tile);
        ll_but[1] = findViewById(R.id.misc_but3_layout);
        ll_but[2] = findViewById(R.id.misc_but2_layout);
        ll_but[3] = findViewById(R.id.faqs_tile);
        ll_but[4] = findViewById(R.id.mohfw_ll2);
        ll_but[5] = findViewById(R.id.mohfw_ll3);
        ll_but[6] = findViewById(R.id.mohfw_ll4);
        ll_but[7] = findViewById(R.id.mohfw_ll5);


        int[] btnToAdd = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7};

        for (int i = 0; i < btnToAdd.length; i++) {
            ll_but[btnToAdd[i]].setOnClickListener(this);
        }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = null;

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.flipperLeft:
                viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(anim1);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(anim4);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
                break;
            case R.id.flipperRight:
                viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(anim2);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(anim3);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                break;
            case R.id.misc_but2_layout:
                i = new Intent(homeActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.misc_but3_layout:
                i = getMythIntent(this);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.success_stories_tile:
                i = getSuccessStoriesIntent(this);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.faqs_tile:
                i = getFAQsIntent(this);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.mohfw_ll2:
            case R.id.mohfw_ll3:
            case R.id.mohfw_ll4:
            case R.id.mohfw_ll5:
                i = getTwitterIntent ( this );
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                i = null;
                break;
        }

    }
```

This is working for me but I would really like to know if there is a better implementation for the same.

Comment: use this lib  https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: isn't that deprecated now?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio now has something like Butterknife implemented in their IDE now, therefore, you can just use `<YourLayoutName>Binding binding = <YourLayoutName>Binding.inflate();` in your onCreateView()

As example:
`LoginFragmentBinding binding = LoginFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);`

With that, you can use for example `binding.miscBut3Layout.setOnClickListener(this);` instead of the `getViewById` that can return an exception.

Another approach for your Listeners is to put them in the XML with the view with the attribute `android:onclick=""` with this, you don't need to create an array for the views.